# How to hide currency symbol in input field in Gravity Forms

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, gravityforms

I am using Gravity forms plugin with WordPress.

I have a product field in which user can enter their desired amount and make a donation.

The input field automatically gets the '€' symbol on the right side. I do not want this to appear in the input field.

I have added a code to functions.php file but it the plugin/theme seems to override it. Here's the code I added

```
add_filter( 'gform_currencies', function( $currencies ) {
 $currencies['EUR']['symbol_left'] = '';
 $currencies['EUR']['symbol_right'] = '';
 return $currencies;
} );
```

But the symbol keeps on appearing on the right side automatically.

I have also tried using jQuery but it messes up the predefined values and makes it a blank field. Here's my jQuery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(".ginput_amount").click(function() {
var text = jQuery( this ).text().replace('€','');
jQuery(".ginput_amount").val(text);
});
</script>
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue with gravity forms before? Would really appreciate your help.